# boolean columns appear as yes/no in datagrdiview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a bound DataGridView use text cell for boolean values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033282/can-a-bound-datagridview-use-text-cell-for-boolean-values)

In windows, `DataGridView`, I do bind the object array list.
and here, boolean properties are appeared as CheckBox over the grid.

I want to display 'Yes'/'No' instead of CheckBox control in DataGridView.

I tried to used `CellFormatting` event, and it shows me error as

> Format Exception:, No/yes is not a a valid boolean.

I don't have access to database query to handle this.

I need to handle this in DataGridView only. (not at database side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

`dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;`

Manually type in the dataProperty name that the datagridView can map to and do

```
dgv.DataSource = mysource.Select(m=> new{Col1 = m.Property1, 
                                         Col2 = m.property2, 
                                         Col3 = ((m.property3) ? "Yes":"No")})
                                         .ToList();
```

Your Col3 on your DataGridView will then need to be a text instead of a checkbox.