# C# DatagridView - Disable autoconversion bool values to checkbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, boolean

I have a DataTable with some boolean columns and when i use as Datagridview datasource, the Datagridview display those boolean cells as checkbox.
Is it possible avoid it? 
I need string cells

Thanks
EDIT: i can edit the datatable if it's easier

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a bound DataGridView use text cell for boolean values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033282/can-a-bound-datagridview-use-text-cell-for-boolean-values)

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways for it:

1. In `DataGridView` set property `AutoGenerateColumns = false`, then create columns in the designer or by code.
   For `bool` field use column of `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` type.
   `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` will convert `bool` to the text automatically as `True` or `False`

Predefined columns can be good solution, because you can control how data are displayed to the user, and values remain in original types.

2. Convert value to the string in the datasource by changing sql query or manipulating your `DataTable`

```cs
DataTable newDataTable = yourDataTable.Clone();
newDataTable.Columns["BoolTypeColumnName"].DataType = typeof(bool);
foreach (DataRow row in yourDataTable.Rows) 
{
    newDataTable.ImportRow(row);
}
this.YourDataGridView.DataSource = newDataTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

In RowDataBound event you can update the value with string alternative

Some thing like this..

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = Convert.ToBoolean(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["DataColumn"]) == true ? "Yes" : "No";
        }
```

Hope this may help...

Comment: Doesn't work with a Datagridview, the column is still boolean, no text allowed

Comment: `RowDataBound` is event of the `DataGrid` control, which is ASP.NET control not Winforms