# Boolean property displaying as checkbox in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Data class whos methods query data from SQL tables, create new instances of the appropriate entity with the queried data, and store the instance of the entity in a list which is then returned.

I then use the list to set the DataSource property of a datagridview to display all of the found records.

However, some of my entities have a bool property, and rather than displaying it as "true" or "false", the DataGridView displays them as an unchecked checkbox.

Is there a way to change this so that it actually displays "true" or "false? Or better yet, any custom text like "ACTIVE" or "INACTIVE"?

Comment: Duplicate of [C# DatagridView - Disable autoconversion bool values to checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31427276/8967612), [show Yes/NO instead True/False in datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980981/show-yes-no-instead-true-false-in-datagridview)

Comment: The first post shows you how to prevent the auto-creation of a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn and display True/False instead. The second post shows you how to display a custom string instead of True/False.

Comment: You could use a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn bound to a simple 2 element list of a string/bool tuple. I'll post an answer there